# Upgraded Magento from 1.9.3.4 to 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento-1.9

I upgraded Magento from 1.9.3.4 to 1.9.3.6 and now store is working well but products showing only in categories but not on the home page in "new/featured" sections.

Also when I'm trying to add new product and trying to upload image progress bar going to 100% and gives message "Image was not uploaded"...

Everything worked fine on 1.9.3.4.

Comment: did you refresh you cache..? you are using same database or you changed your database after migration?

Comment: All I did is upgrade my existing worked well magento 1.9.3.4 to 1.9.3.6 from Connect Manager. Nothing more, and yes I already flushed cache. Still can't see products on home page in Featured and New sections. But all products showed in Categories. And also can't upload images for new products with error - "image was not uploaded" All folder are 755 and all files are 644

Comment: just check your product is new date and feature attribute is selected are not..

Comment: Already checked and yes new end/start dates are correct and featured  box checked

Comment: Got the same issue, using the auto upgrade feature in my cpanel. What I did is redowloaded the entire 1.9.3.6 package at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download, the merged it with my current M1 store @ 1.9.3.4 and everything seems to work just fine. Have you tried downloading from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for one problem.

Featured and new products was not showing at homepage.
I  just add static blocks names used on my homepage for featured and new products in to Permissions->Blocks and allowed them.

But product image uploading still not working :(
After press browse and pick picture, pressing upload - progress bar goes to 100% and returns error message "file was not uploaded"

Comment: check your media folder exists in root or not.

Comment: Of course yes media folder exist in root. All existing products showing great all existing pictures showing, media folder and all sub-folders have 755 permission. I also tried to give it 777 nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on one of our stores. For us it was the .htaccess file in the media folder. Please check your server logs for any errors in the htaccess.
For us the following settings were blocked on server level:

Options All -Indexes

Options -ExecCGI

Comment: Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Please check your server logs if any of these settings are not allowed. Not the Magento logs, but the server logs.